# Dynamically ItemId in Sencha Touch app

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch

I am working in an app based in Sencha Touch 2, and I have different buttons with the possibility of different badge text. My current code in the view is:

```
items: [
            {
                xtype: 'button',
                text: xx.Text.getText('SC_I_CONDITIONS_BTN'),
                itemId: 'setItemConditions',
                cls:'setConditions'
            }
        ],
```

My question is, how can I specify different badge texts? Each one has different total, in my app you can generate different buttons dinamically with the same itemID

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand your problem. You want to dynamically create buttons and what you want to do with itemId. Can you provide an example of your problem?

Comment: Buttons are created dinamically, but I should identify of different way each one, for example, "button-1", "button-2" being the number added dinamically to the itemId.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to set badge text dynamically first get button in controller like that

```
Ext.getCmp("setItemConditions").setBadgeText('newBadgeText');
```